# Animation Nodes: How to create splines from two different points in order to create procedural telegraph poles?

Tags: animation-nodes

I've reached the limit of my ability with AN and need some help creating procedural telegraph or telephone poles.

This is what I've managed so far:
[image]

I've managed to generate splines from the origin of each pole. The origin is at the top of the pole and not the base. Each pole is randomly generated with random heights and rotations. Each new pole automatically creates a wire using spline from points. The whole system animates in nicely based on distance to a Null object. The Wire Sag is done using a subprogram - I'm open to better ways of doing things - I would love the wires to swing or bobble as they appear but for now, let's stick to the main question.

Here is my Node Setup:

[image]

This is what I'm trying to create:

[image]

With a view to creating more complex wire systems for Pylons.

What I have already tried is Offsetting a duplicate of the spline but that doesn't observe the random rotation of each pole.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**Updated:**

With the help of Omar's answer, I've updated my node tree as seen below:

[image]

And this is the result. The wires are too thick but it's just to illustrate the result.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Rotation To Direction* node can be used to get a vector pointing along the local x axis of the objects, This direction is then added to the location of the object giving you point one, the inverse of that vector is added to the location giving you point two. You now have two points per object, use them in your node tree.

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Thank you @OmarAhmad this was really helpful. I was sure how to make your method procedural and not have to manually create each pole. BUT your answer definitely helped me get to the solution. I've updated my question with the new solution. Side note how are you using AN in 2.8?

Comment: @Alan Porting AN to 2.8 started a while ago. If you want to test it. Compile the blender2.8 branch if you can. Or wait for test builds to be release, probably this month.